# run a function from an input window in java

Tags: java, function, netbeans, input

I am trying to set it up so that when i run the program a dialog window pops up and ask me to input the number of the exercise i want to run. each exercise will be in their own function and the only function that will run will be the one that is entered by the user.

```
package exercises;

import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Exercises {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String JOptionPaneTest = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Run Exercise (1 - ): ");



} 

public static void One (String[] args) {
    // Exercise 1: Write a program that reads an integer between 100 and 999, and finds the reverse of that integer. 
    System.out.println("Running Exercise 1");  
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter Random Number between 100  and 999: ");

    int num = reader.nextInt();

    int digitOne = num % 10;
    int digitTwo = (num / 10) % 10;
    int digitThree = (num / 100);

    System.out.println(digitOne + "" + digitTwo + "" + digitThree);
}
```

}

Comment: You've so far only posted a requirement and some code. What's your question, where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of options that do exactly what you want, e.g. making a switch-statement that delegates to your method or even using reflection to invoke a method based on user input, but what you really want for this is a better design. I'd propose to make an `Exercise` class with a `run()` or `run(String[])` method, put all instances of `Exercise` in an array or `List` and call the selected `Exercise`'s `run()` method when the user selects one.